# What happens to in-progress volley call when app is background'ed

Tags: android, android-volley

What happens to a in-progress volley call when app is backgrounded.

If the app is backgrounded while the volley call is still in progress, will the Response.Listener/Response.ErrorListener() still be called when the app has been backgrounded

And lets say these methods are updating UI, will it be still fine

Or this CASE (App backgrounded when volley call in progress) needs to be handled in a proper way, if yes? how?